# why do we check for filters to be applied twice in sitemesh and other places?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, sitemesh

The simple flow diagram of sitemesh ([here](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh/Flow+Diagram)) shows that they check whether its the first time the filter is being applied or not. I have seen this check in the code of other filters too. I am unable to understand a situation where the same filter can be applied twice for the same request. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Servlet 2.4, filters can be applied to a request invoked via the [request dispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) also.  If the filter is specified to run on includes, or forwards for example it could be executed multiple times.  e.g.

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Logging Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/products/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

So, for example, when a request is handled by a servlet and that servlet forwards the request somewhere else

```
httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/products/somewhereElse").forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
```

, then the filter may run twice.  Once for the original request and then again for the forward providing the URL path and dispatcher configuration allows.